# Fail to change user from postgres to other

Tags: users, password, postgresql

When I try to change user (starting as postgres user) using the command

```
sudo -i -u ubuntu
```

The password for postgres is prompted. Now the postgres account was created upon installing postgres, and I don't know what the password is.
I have tried changing the password in the psql prompt with

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'password';
ALTER ROLE postgres PASSWORD 'password';
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'password';
ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD 'password';
\password ;
```

These have enabled me to set the password for the database server login, but not for the linux user, which makes sense I guess. And trying it with the passwd command doesn't work because it asks for the old password first.
I have added postgres to the /etc/sudoers file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unix user `postgres` and the PostgreSQL user `postgres` are only related by their names, but otherwise are not the same thing.

To be able to change to another user with `sudo` from the `postgres` Unix user account, you will either have to assign the `postgres` user a password, or allow the user to use `sudo` in that way without a password (not something I would recommend).

To reset the `postgres` user password, as root, use

```
# passwd postgres
```

Comment: @dutchJSCOOP Note too that you should actually need to do any interactive work logged in as the `postgres` user. This user is only for running the actual PostgreSQL database.